# Assigning each value as next item in Array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, matrix

I'm new to Scala and am having trouble iterating through an array to assign values to a Matrix. My programming background is mostly Python, so I'm having difficulty seeing the functional way to do this task.

I've got an Array, `val averages = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`, and I've got an empty 3x3 matrix, `M`, made with Scala library `breeze`. I need to take the values from the Array and put them into the matrix.

Normally, I would try something like:

```
 var index = 0
 for(i <- 0 until M.cols)
        for(j <- 0 until M.rows)
            M(i,j) = averages(index)
            index += 1
```

This doesn't work, and results in a matrix simply filled with "1"s. I assume this is because Scala is evaluating `M(i,j) = averages(index)` before it gets to `index += 1`. I've experimented with different types of `for` loops for averages, but can't quite get the result I want:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I know that in Scala with the Random collection you can do this, and fill the matrix with random variables:

```
 val r = new scala.util.Random(0)
 for(i <- 0 until M.rows)
    for(j <- 0 until M.cols)
        M(i, j) = r.nextDouble()
```

But looking at the Scala documentation, `Array` doesn't have the `.next` method.

At any rate, even using `.next` is very iterative, and not a functional solution. Can anyone help me 1) Figure out the proper way to loop through `averages` and/or 2) Figure out a functional way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `val averages = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).toIterator` Now it has a `next`.

Comment: You just need braces (to make a block) around both statements you want executed in your first for-loop. Scala uses {}, not indentation like Python, for  scoping

Comment: You should check library's Scaladoc also, probably there is already a method that you need, like `Matrix.create(3, 3, array)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not just having a brackets issue? The code you provided above looks like it ought to be:

```
 var index = 0
 for(i <- 0 until M.cols)
    for(j <- 0 until M.rows) {
        M(i,j) = averages(index)
        index += 1
    }
```

If you don't include those braces, only the first line of the second for loop will run. Java/Scala rely on these braces to group things. You can't rely on indenting like Python. 
If you don't want to use the index parameter, some math works too:

```
for(i <- 0 until M.cols
    for(j <- 0 until M.rows) {
        M(i, j) = 1 + i + j * M.cols
```

Answer (score 2):

Copying data from one existing collection to another is, by definition, relying on side effects to accomplish your goals.  A more FP approach is to build a new one directly from the old.

I don't have Breeze installed but, according to the [scaladocs](http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/#breeze.linalg.Matrix$), something like this should be possible.

```
Matrix((0 until colLen).map(x => averages.slice(x*rowLen, (x+1)*rowLen)))
```